# Determine if FTP path is file or directory

Tags: c++, winapi, ftp

I have to fix a bug deeply buried in legacy code. This code makes a call to [FtpFindFirstFileW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384146(v=vs.85).aspx) to collect info about files on an FTP server. It then iterates over the files using [InternetFindNextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384698(v=vs.85).aspx), puts the info into a vector and returns this vector.

The problem, however, is that the "path" passed to [FtpFindFirstFileW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384146(v=vs.85).aspx) could also be the path to a single file. [FtpFindFirstFileW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384146(v=vs.85).aspx) is fine with that an just returns info about this single file. But afterwards I see no possibility to reliably get the full path to the file (i.e. the path passed to [FtpFindFirstFileW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384146(v=vs.85).aspx) in the first place). The [WIN32_FIND_DATA structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740(v=vs.85).aspx) only contains the filename without its path.

My method could be called with a path like

1. empty path (e.g. list files in current directory)
2. path/to/some/subdir
3. path/to/file.txt
4. file.txt (e.g. just a filename)

If ever possible I would like to just change this single method to reduce the risk of breaking the legacy code.

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA FileData;
FtpFindFirstFile(hFTP, Path.c_str(), &FileData, 0, 0);

do
{
    auto PathToFile = Path + FileData.cFileName; // wrong result if Path is full path to file (e.g. Path = path/to/file.txt and FileData.cFileName = file.txt)
    auto PathToFile = Path; // wrong result if Path is path to directory (e.g. Path = path/ and FileData.cFileName = file.txt)
    auto PathToFile = FileData.cFileName; // wrong result if Path path to directory (e.g. Path = path/ and FileData.cFileName = file.txt)
} while(InternetFindNextFile(Hdl,&FileData));
```

I dont see methods to check if a path is a directory/file or to get the full path to a file in the [Windows-FTP-API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384180(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

**EDIT**

Regarding the comments suggesting to use FileData.dwFileAttributes to distinguish between files and directories:

If I call FtpFindFirstFile with the path `/foo/bar` I might get a single result with `FileData.cFilename = bar`. If `FileData.dwFileAttributes` has the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` bit not set I don't see a way to know if this is because `/file/bar` is a file or because `/file/bar` is a directory and there is a file `/foo/bar/bar`.

Comment: I don't see a way making that distinction by using the API. Why do you need the function to also accept a file path in the first place? IMO querying directory content and asking for information about a single file is semantically different, so it shouldn't be handled by a *single* function.

Comment: @zett42 I agree but this is how the legacy code is atm. I would like to make as little changes as possible to reduce the risk of breaking it. Additionally I dont know how to make the distinction a priori either since I would face the same problem. There simply is no sate where I know if the path is a file or a directory. It is user input.

Comment: `if(FileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)...` should tell you if path is directory.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani If for a path like `/foo/bar` I get a result with `cFilename = bar` and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` is not set for this result. How should I know if this is because `/file/bar` is a file or because there is actually a file `/foo/bar/bar`?